# Health page in apache mod_proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy

I have one apache with balancer, and 2 tomcats.

I'm trying to use apache mod proxy and want to set healthy page (so if one of my WAR does not work, requests will not be directed to it), which will help the apache decide to fail server if this page is down.

Is there any way to do this with apache?
Or is there an option in tomcat to close if deploy went wrong?

Comment: but if your WAR has failed deployment, doesn't the Tomcat return some error code and the balancer direct next requests to the other server?

Comment: No, it will return 404...